# What is causing the text in my button ("View all content") to appear 3D when zoomed in

Tags: html, css

You can see the grey-ish shadow background underneath the text on the button on regular view and upon hovering. I'm not sure if it's because of the bootstrap theme I am using (relatively new + self-teaching). Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/minacosentino/pen/JyBQxM

```
.btn-primary {
  font-family: "Montserrat", arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .25rem;
  text-indent: .75rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  background: #4fd2c2;
  border-color: #4fd2c2;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 0rem;  
  }

  .btn-primary:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #4fd2c2;
    border: 2px solid #4fd2c2;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Inspect your element and start disabling styles one by one: that is a good start. Hint: it has something to do with a `text-shadow` property.

Comment: thanks, terry - i will keep this in mind going forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on .btn-primary

```
text-shadow:none;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKVByp

Comment: Worked perfectly ! Thanks

Comment: Mark it as answer to close the topic :)

Answer (score 0):

The `.btn-primary` has a `:hover` css with `box-shadow` property which cause the d3-like effect when you hover that button:

```
.btn-primary:hover {
    background: #4fd2c2;
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0rem 0.75rem 3rem #D8D8D8;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

Here is a snippet for that:

```css
.btn-primary {
    background: #4fd2c2;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.btn-primary:hover {
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0rem 0.75rem 3rem #D8D8D8;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-primary">This is a test</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dekel - I edited question to indicate I meant the text within the button, not the actual button. Sorry about the confusion.